# Checking Firebase value and show wrong result

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

It has to work this way. User have 10 fields in DB. System need to check all fields and if in at least one field it finds 1 value DEFAULT it shows dialog. In case when theres no fields with value DEFAULT it has to be hidden. But in my case everytime it shows dialog and doesnt matter it has default value or not.

Method for check value

```
  mUserDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            needInfo = dataSnapshot.child("drink_status").getValue().toString().equals("default") ||
                    dataSnapshot.child("ethnicity").getValue().toString().equals("default") ||
                    dataSnapshot.child("faith").getValue().toString().equals("default") ||
                    dataSnapshot.child("gender").getValue().toString().equals("default") ||
                    dataSnapshot.child("hobby").getValue().toString().equals("default") ||
                    dataSnapshot.child("how_tall").getValue().toString().equals("default") ||
                    dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString().equals("default") ||
                    dataSnapshot.child("languages").getValue().toString().equals("default") ||
                    dataSnapshot.child("number_of_kids").getValue().toString().equals("default") ||
                    dataSnapshot.child("relationship_status").getValue().toString().equals("default") ||
                    dataSnapshot.child("smoking_status").getValue().toString().equals("default") ||
                    dataSnapshot.child("want_children_or_not").getValue().toString().equals("default");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

Here is method which checking for If Else

```
public void userNeedToAddInfo(){
    if (iMainInteractor.checkForUserInfo()){
        getViewState().checkingForUserInformation();
    } else {
    }
```

Code connected threw

```
 @Override
public boolean checkForUserInfo() {
   return iFirebaseRepository.checkingForFirstNeededInformationOfUser();
}
```

Comment: change this `dataSnapshot.child("drink_status").getValue().toString().equals("default")` to `dataSnapshot.child("drink_status").getValue().toString().trim().toLowerCase().equals("default")`

Comment: How are these two pieces of code connected?

Comment: @AndréKool added that method

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh didn't help

Comment: you have to do this for all `dataSnapshot.child` calls

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh yes i put trim to each case. But doesnt work

Comment: then it's means data is something else so see the output of all similar `dataSnapshot.child("drink_status").getValue().toString()` values or there could be some logical mistake

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh i think problem is in logic but dont know where mistake

Comment: Please add the FULL code, its still not clear how your listener is connected to those functions and i never see the needInfo variabl being used besides inside the listener. Also can you check the order in which your code is executing? (given firebase is asynchronous)